# Como criar uma função para meu IF com a Public Function da Class?

Tags: php, mysql

Bem, possuo a seguinte `public function`:

```
/**
* Mostrar notícias
*
* @param string $featured - Define se será noticia de destaque ou padrão que mostrará
*
* @param string $date - Define o tempo em que mostrará as notícias recentes (ex: notícias recentes dentro de 7 dias)
*
* @param string $limit - Define o total de notícias que será mostrada por vez dentro da função
*/
public function newsShow($featured = 'No', $date = 7, $limit) {
    $DB = new Database();
    $Translate = new Translate();
    $M = new Modulos();

    $stm = $DB->readDB('news', 'WHERE Featured = "'.$featured.'" AND Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-'.$date.' AND CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT '.$limit);
    if (!$stm) {
        echo '';
    } else {
        foreach ($stm as $key) {
            // Envia as informações do banco de dados para as gets \\
            $this->SetID($key["ID"]);
            $this->SetTitle($key["Title"]);
            $this->SetSubTitle($key["SubTitle"]);
            $this->SetCategory($key["Category"]);
            $this->SetMessage($key["Message"]);
            $this->SetFeatured($key["Featured"]);
            $this->SetDate($key["Date"]);

            // Define a tradução dos termos achados no banco de dados \\
            $title = json_decode($this->GetTitle(), true);
            $subtitle = json_decode($this->GetSubTitle(), true);
            $title_name = $title[U_LANG].PHP_EOL;
            $subtitle_name = $subtitle[U_LANG].PHP_EOL;
            $url = $M->tirarAcentos($Translate->set('href')['news'].$this->GetID().'-'.$title_name, true);

            // Envia as informações do banco de dados para as gets \\
            $this->SetURL($url);
            $this->SetTitle($title_name);
            $this->SetSubTitle($subtitle_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Até ai tudo bem, e também a chamo assim fora da class:

```
<?php echo $News->newsShow('Yes', 7, '0,1'); ?>
```

Mas o que eu desejo é fazer uma verificação fora da class para vê se possui um notícia a ser mostrada, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php if (função) { echo $News->newsShow('Yes', 7, '0,1'); } else { echo null; } ?>
```

Porém é ai que está, não sei como fazer isso, pois preciso mostrar uma div dentro desse `IF`, ficará assim olha:

```
<?php if (funcao) { echo $News->newsShow('Yes', 7, '0,1');
            echo '<div class="ak-block-title">
                <a href="'.$News->GetURL().'" class="ak-title-link">
                    <div class="ak-layer">
                        <span class="ak-title"><?php '.$News->GetTitle().'</span>
                        <br><span class="ak-subtitle"><?php '.$News->GetSubTitle().'</span> <span class="ak-banner-more">+</span><br>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>'; } else { echo null; } ?>
```

Bem é isso que eu desejo, mas não sei o que colocar na função do `IF` pra fazer esse rodamento, por favor me ajude!

Comment: Você pode fazer um `select COUNT` para verificar se o número de notícias é maior do que 0, caso for, você exibe a `div`

Comment: Bem, boa ideia, mas ai que está, como farei esse COUNT? Por que, quero usar essa mesma função em várias áreas do meu site, por isso, fiz ela em class, para não ter que ficar criando a mesma chamada da query toda vez que eu precisar utilizar, porém eu tenho um project ao qual eu chamava com .TPL mas travava demais o site, então resolvi chamar assim. Podes me ensinar a como fazer essa chamada que você me solicitou?

Comment: Pq não cria uma função que retorne o número de registros da tabela? Na verificação você faria assim: `if(retornoLinhas() > 0)` ai você coloca seu código

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, você diz meio que criar uma Get dentro da própria função, ficando: `if($News->GetResult() > 0) { echo código }?` Ai dentro da função eu criaria algo do tipo: `$this->SetResult()`, mas ai que está, pensando desta maneira, ainda ficarei com dúvida na hora de criar o SetResult, a menos que nele eu faça a mesma coisa do início, ficando assim: `$this->SetResult(!$stm);` será que funcionará?

Comment: Se quiser posso fazer um exemplo do que acho melhor, mas usarei `PDO` para ilustrar a consulta.

Comment: Opa, claro, pode fazer em PDO mesmo, eu consigo depois passar pro meu tranquilamente. Será de grande ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se precisas realizar a mesma verificação diversas vezes, você pode criar uma função que retorne `true` caso o número de linhas encontradas na tabela seja maior que 0, se não, nada será feito.

Poderia criar a função da seguinte forma:

```
  public function HasData() {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) as qt FROM suatabela');
        $sql->execute();
        $data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($data['qt'] != '0' ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;    
  }
```

No seu `if` você faria assim:

```
<?php if (HasData()): echo $News->newsShow('Yes', 7, '0,1'); ?> 
   <div class="ak-block-title">
        <a href="<?=$News->GetURL()?>" class="ak-title-link">
           <div class="ak-layer">
               <span class="ak-title"><?=$News->GetTitle()?></span>
                 <br><span class="ak-subtitle"><?=$News->GetSubTitle()?></span> 
                  <span class="ak-banner-more">+</span><br>
             </div>
          </a>
     </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Obs: Não postei partes de `conexão` com o banco pois não vem ao caso e acredito que você tem conhecimento para entender o funcionamento do código.

Comment: Não precisa da parte de `conexão` isso eu sei fazer, bem, olhei seu método, é ele é o que eu preciso, obrigado :D

Comment: @Akatsuki que bom poder lhe ajudar! :D

Comment: Bem ficou assim agora rs:

public function hasData() {
  $DB = new Database();

  $stm = $DB->readDB('news', null, 'COUNT(ID) as QT');
  if (!$stm) {
   return false;
  } else {
   foreach ($stm as $key) {
    if ($key['QT'] != 0) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Show de bola! Deu certo?

Comment: Bem, fiz uns ajustes :D, agora ficou bem melhor rs

Comment: olha como ficou o novo script: https://pastebin.com/v2fNkq26

Comment: na própria verificação pra vê se possui registro banco de dados, já puis logo a definição de destaque, entre datas e o limit, assim na própria `if` já defino e só mostra a notícia embaixo rs :D. Obrigado por tudo!